# Setting a default value in Scala/Slick

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0

I'm trying to persist data with Scala/Slick in play framework. I'm sending a request via json and I'm trying to validate said request by matching it to a model like this:

```
request.body.asJson.map(_.validate[Foo] match {...}
```

The question is: How do I set a default column value (to false)?

This is my evolution file:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo(
    ...
    deleted BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    ...
)
```

This is my model (.scala):

```
case class Foo(
                    ...
                    deleted: Boolean,
                    ...)
```

This is my dao (.scala):

```
 class Foo(tag: Tag) extends TableFoo(tag, "Foo"){
            ...
                def deleted = column[Boolean]("deleted", O.Default(false))
            ...

                def * = (..., deleted, ...) <> ((Foo.apply _).tupled, Foo.unapply)
        }
```

The problem occurs while validating the request to the model. When defining `deleted` as `Option[Boolean]`, it writes `None/Null` for the column `deleted`. When defining it as `Boolean`, the validation fails. 
Presumably, because the request is missing the attribute `deleted`.

Why defining a default value, when the validation fails after all or in the case of `Option[Boolean]` just writes `None/Null`? Is there an easy way to set a reliable default value in Scala/Slick or Evolutions?

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: @ezzarghili no, not so far. I just pass a default value from the front-end to the back-end for `deleted`. That's not what I wanted, since my back-end should function regardless of what's coming.

Comment: actually I got something working, define the default in the case class ```case class Foo(
                    ... deleted: Boolean=false,
                    ...)``` 
Not sure which version of play you're using but I think since 2.6 the json lib has a new functionally to allow for defaults ```Json.WithDefaultValues```, I use an implicit format for this 
 ```implicit val ModelFormat: OFormat[Model] = Json.using[Json.WithDefaultValues].format[Model]

```

Comment: @ezzarghili yeah I tried that once, but it didn't work for me. Maybe I just need to update my current version and the format. Thanks!